# C++ output all members in a object

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, cout

So far I have defined a simple class...

```
class person {
public:
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    string age;
    string pstcode;
};
```

...then added some members and values to an object named "bill"...

```
int main() {
    person bill;
    bill.firstname = "Bill";
    bill.lastname = "Smith";
    bill.age = "24";
    bill.pstcode = "OX29 8DJ";
}
```

But how would you simply output all those values? Would you use a for loop to iterate over each member?

Comment: Well, you could overload the `operator <<` for your class.

Comment: Define _simply_. You can't loop-through them, since member fields are not an array. You could overload `operator<<` though.

Comment: c++ doesn't have native reflection, so you have manually "iterate" over the members of the class.(some libraries allow some kind of reflection).

Comment: Why is `age` a string?  Usually, `age` is an unsigned integer variable (unsigned because you can't have a negative age).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: My age is "Greater than the age of my sister" or "Depends or the current date" ;-).

Comment: @Jarod42: The *difference* can be negative, but have you met somebody who is -20 years old?  The `age` data member is an attribute of the `Person`, not the difference between persons.  I could possibly see a negative age as the duration before birth, but years?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I provided examples of "string" ages. Negative ages can be obtained depending of referential for "baby" ;) Anyway, it was a joke.

Answer (score 4):

I typically override `operator <<`, so that my objects are as easy to print as any built-in object.

Here is one way to override `operator <<`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const person& p)
{
    return os << "("
              << p.lastname << ", "
              << p.firstname << ": "
              << p.age << ", "
              << p.pstcode
              << ")";
}
```

And then to use it:

```
std::cout << "Meet my friend, " << bill << "\n";
```

Here is a complete program using this technique:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class person {
public:
    std::string firstname;
    std::string lastname;
    std::string age;
    std::string pstcode;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const person& p)
    {
        return os << "("
                  << p.lastname << ", "
                  << p.firstname << ": "
                  << p.age << ", "
                  << p.pstcode
                  << ")";
    }

};

int main() {
    person bill;
    bill.firstname = "Bill";
    bill.lastname = "Smith";
    bill.age = "24";
    bill.pstcode = "OX29 8DJ";

    std::cout << "Meet my friend, " << bill << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically, you output each element using an `ostream`:

```
class Person
{
public:
    void Print_As_CSV(std::ostream& output)
    {
       output << firstname << ",";
       output << lastname  << ",";
       output << age       << ",";
       output << pstcode   << "\n";
    }
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    string age;
    string pstcode;
};
```

There may be different methods of printing, which is why I didn't overload `operator <<`.  For example, one data member per line would be another popular scenario.

**Edit 1: Why not looping?**
The `class` has separate fields, which is why you can't iterate over the members.

If you want to iterator or loop over the members, you either have to have an iterator for your class or use a container, such as `std::vector`, that provides iteration.